# rollover over image, different image appears below

Tags: css, hover, mouseover, rollover

I'm trying to make a grid of images that once you hover over one, it's webpage title appears below it, as well as the other images around it changing in opacity.

I have managed to create the opacity mouseover effect I want, but now I'm having trouble making the page heading images appear as you hover over the corresponding image. I hope that makes sense

Hope someone can help. Here is my code

HTML:

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 140px; top: 0px;">
        <img src="window.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
    <div id="windowimages">
    <a class="image-one"></a><a href="https://example-site.com/music/">
      <img src="pic1.jpg/>
       <a class="image-two"></a><a href="https://example-site.com/dance/">
      <img 
    src="pic2.jgp"/>
       <a class="image-three"></a><a href="https://example-site.com/art/">
      <img 
    src="pic3.jpg"  />
       <a class="image-four"></a><a href="https://example-site.com/aboutus/">
      <img 
    src="pic4.jpg"/>
         </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
}
#windowimages {
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 198px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:1px;
  overflow:hidden
}
 #windowimages img {
   width:90px;
  height:90px;
   margin: 3px;
   cursor:pointer;
  -webkit-transition:opacity 0.26s ease-out;   
  -moz-transition:opacity 0.26s ease-out;   
  -ms-transition:opacity 0.26s ease-out;   
  -o-transition:opacity 0.26s ease-out;   
   transition:opacity 2s ease-in-out;  
}

#windowimages:hover img {
  opacity:0.55;
}

#windowimages:hover img:hover {
  opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: clarify what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, it seems like what you want to do is add a title to each image on hover.

Check out this example I wrote: http://jsfiddle.net/arthurcamara/chbsL3pq/

The key part to adding the title was `.image:hover:after` as you can see above and in the code below:

```
.grid:hover .image:hover:after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    width: 90px;
    padding: 5px;
    content: attr(data-title);
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I changed your markup a bit as well to make it more semantic. Check out the example and let me know if that helped :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Arthur!! that was more or less what I wanted :) Just going to adjust the positioning of the title texts now

Comment: Although this works, I realised I would prefer if the page titles would appear BELOW the grid images, and in the same place. I have created the text images I want to appear, so essentially what I want to know is how to hover over one of the grid images (in the way Arthur's example shows) and that triggers the respective page title jpg to appear?